# block does not append

Tags: express, pug

My script does not append to the javascript block.

layout.jade:

```
block javascript
    script(src='/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

person.jade:

```
Extends layout
   .....

block append javascript
   script(src="/javascripts/admin/person.js")
```

The result is the person.js is on top of jquery:

```
<script src="/javascripts/admin/person.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: jade is case-sensitive. You need "extends" with a lowercase "e", for one thing. Fixing that and saving your snippets as files results in the expected output for me.

Comment: Why *block append javascript* in **person.jade** ? it should be only *block javascript*.

Comment: @PalakBhansali because he doesn't want to overwrite the original block, he wants to append to the block.

Answer (score 0):

As [Peter Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266795/peter-lyons) pointed out in the comments, jade is case sensitive and you need to use "extends" not "Extends".